# Is there a quick and easy way in OpenCV to compute the gradient of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

Using the newest OpenCV, is there an easy way to compute the gradient image of a specific cv::Mat?

Comment: A sample image, and expected results would be nice.

Comment: Are you looking for the Sobel operator, which calculates derivatives? [Documentation here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sobel).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the typical [image gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient); you can compute these quite easily with the [Sobel](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sobel) operator as mentioned by Chris. Have a look at the Sobel Derivatives tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives). You may also be interested in the [Laplace](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#laplacian) operator, and its [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html#laplace-operator).

Here is a short snippet of computing the X and Y gradients using Sobel:

```
cv::Mat src = ...; // Fill the input somehow.

cv::Mat Dx;
cv::Sobel(src, Dx, CV_64F, 1, 0, 3);

cv::Mat Dy;
cv::Sobel(src, Dy, CV_64F, 0, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient, you can do:

```
IplImage * diffsizekernel(IplImage *img, int f, int c) {
    float dkernel[] =  {-1, 0, 1};

    CvMat kernel = cvMat(f, c, CV_32FC1, dkernel);

    IplImage *imgDiff = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width, img->height), IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);

    cvFilter2D( img, imgDiff, &kernel, cvPoint(-1,-1) );

    return imgDiff;
}

IplImage * diffx(IplImage *img) {
    return diffsizekernel(img, 3, 1);
}

IplImage * diffy(IplImage *img) {
    return diffsizekernel(img, 1, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mevatron said: the Sobel and the Laplace operators are powerful, but don't forget about the Scharr operator, which has greater accuracy at a 3×3 kernel than the Sobel has.